# "html agility pack" like module for perl

Tags: html, perl, beautifulsoup, html-agility-pack

Can anyone recommend a good module like "html agility pack"(.net) or "Beautiful Soup" for perl?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=HTML%3A%3ATreeBuilder&mode=all) and friends (such as HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath). [::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML::TreeBuilder::LibXML) is good if you need speed.